# Why do parasites involved with malaria going into red blood cells?

Tags: human-biology

When someone is infected with the mosquito bug which has the parasite, this parasite will go into the liver to grow. Afterwards he goes in the red blood cells and blocking the vains of the brains. But why do they leave the liver and go into the red blood cells?